# Error in plugin solidity-coverage: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Tags: hardhat, testing, solidity-coverage, coverage

when running `yarn hardhat coverage`, it compiled the solidity files successfully and then gave the following error message:

`Error in plugin solidity-coverage: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')`

would appreciate any help